# Replacing statically referenced method in Java

Tags: java, reflection, methods, static, bcel

I have a class like below with a method that just returns a String, but I want to modify what it returns from another class, without hardcoding it myself.

```
public class Name {
    public static String getName() {
        return "MyName";
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this? I tried BCEL but that didn't seem to change the return value.

Edit: This is for a mod. I'm trying to make it completely independant from the existing code, by not modifying it.

Thanks.

Comment: why do you want to do it? You can do it by setter method instead?

Comment: `Name.getName()` method returns the hardcoded value(as above) or static class field?

Comment: It returns a hardcoded value like above. If the value were a class variable I could use simple Reflection to modify its value, but it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you *sure* you've tried BCEL? I created a fully-working example [here](http://pastie.org/private/p05jdjpxskuj2ede0jsm2w).

```
JavaClass target;
try {
  target = Repository.lookupClass("Target");
} catch (final ClassNotFoundException ex) {
  throw new RuntimeException("unable to resolve Target", ex);
}
final ClassGen targetGen = new ClassGen(target);
final ConstantPoolGen pool = targetGen.getConstantPool();
final ConstantMethodref ref = (ConstantMethodref) pool.getConstant(
    pool.lookupMethodref("Name", "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;"));
ref.setClassIndex(pool.lookupClass("Target"));
ref.setNameAndTypeIndex(pool.addNameAndType("$Name$getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;"));
final InstructionList code = new InstructionList();
final InstructionFactory factory = new InstructionFactory(targetGen, pool);
code.append(factory.createConstant("overriden-name"));
code.append(factory.createReturn(Type.STRING));
code.setPositions();
final MethodGen methodGen = new MethodGen(
    Constants.ACC_PRIVATE | Constants.ACC_SYNTHETIC | Constants.ACC_STATIC,
    Type.STRING, new Type[0], new String[0], "$Name$getName", "Target",
    code, pool);
methodGen.setMaxLocals(0);
methodGen.setMaxStack(1);
targetGen.addMethod(methodGen.getMethod());
try {
  targetGen.getJavaClass().dump("Target.class");
} catch (final IOException ex) {
  throw new RuntimeException("unable to save Target", ex);
}
```

> ```
> C:\dev\scrap>javac Target.java
> C:\dev\scrap>java Target
> original-name
> C:\dev\scrap>javac -cp .;bcel-6.0.jar Instrumenter.java
> C:\dev\scrap>java -cp .;bcel-6.0.jar Instrumenter
> C:\dev\scrap>java Target
> overriden-name
> ```

Comment: Hm, I need to add BCEL to the classpath, I just have its source in my project and have my mod run this method and I get an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException -1`. I'll have a play around with it, thanks.

Comment: This was mainly a proof-of-concept, but I can verify it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter into method

```
 public class Main {
        getName("newName")
    }

public class Name {
    public static String getName(String name) {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, however I cannot modify the existing class that returns the String. I'm trying to do it without making changes to existing code. (Yes it's a mod)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a `-javaagent` agent which will use something like [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/) or [bcel](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/) to modify the bytecode of `Name` class such that the static method will return another string. Many mock testing frameworks - for e.g. [powermock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) or [jmockit](http://code.google.com/p/jmockit/) - can do this.

**EDIT**: [Here](http://pastie.org/4584980) is some sample code to get you started. This is a javaagent which can modify a given public static method which returns a `String` to return another constant `String`. For e.g:

```
public class TestMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(Name.getName());
    }
}

class Name
{
    public static String getName()
    {
        return "ORIGINAL";
    }
}

$ java -cp build/libs/bciex.jar mycompany.myapp.TestMain
ORIGINAL
$ java -cp build/libs/bciex.jar -javaagent:build/libs/bciex.jar="mycompany.myapp.TestMain|getName|SOME_STRING" mycompany.myapp.TestMain
Agent loaded; will modify [getName] method of classes in [mycompany.myapp.TestMain] to return [SOME_STRING]
SOME_STRING
$
```